# Stop Task after Timer is out

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

How can I stop my Task when the Timer is out or if the algorithm is finished? The Object (Student) has a long variable "dyingTime". After Time is over it should print it out. Or if the algorithm is over it should print out something else.
Here is my code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (run) {
                    doAlgorithm();
                    sysout(" Beendet ", timeStart);
                } else {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                    sysout(" Tot ", timeStart);
                }
            }
        }; timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, dyingTime);
```

Where do i put run = false?
Right now the algorithm goes only 5 millisecs, although the dyingTime is set to 1000.

Comment: I removed the `algorithm` tag is this is not a question about an algorithm.

Comment: You do not want TimerTask. You need a Future. See ExecutorService.